# How to Center Masonry Container

Tags: css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to center a masonry container on a page. At the moment, it's aligned to the left. I have margin auto in my CSS and isFitWidth: true in JS, but neither seems to be doing anything. I've also tried putting display:block in my CSS.

This is the HTML;

```
<div id="masonry_container" class="group">

<div class="masonry_item">
    <a href="http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp"target="_blank">
    <img src="images/storyville_home.png" alt="Storyville Entertainment"/>
    <h3>Storyville Entertainment</h3></a>
</div><!--masonry_item-->


<div class="masonry_item">
    <a href="http://www.ducklingfarm.com"target="_blank">
    <img src="images/udof_home.jpg" alt="Ugly Duckling Organic Farm"/>
    <h3>Ugly Duckling Organic Farm</h3></a>
</div> <!--masonry_item-->


<div class="masonry_item">
    <a href="http://www.underdonk.com"target="_blank">
    <img src="images/underdonk_home.png" alt="underdonk"/>
    <h3>Underdonk</h3></a>
</div> <!--masonry_item-->

<div class="masonry_item">
    <a href="http://www.jaeeunlee.com" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/jaeeunlee_home.png" alt="jaeeunlee"/>
    <h3>www.jaeeunlee.com</h3></a>
</div> <!--masonry_item-->

<div class="masonry_item">
    <img src="images/goindoor_hospitals.png" alt="goindoor"/>
    <h3>Goindoor</h3>
</div> <!--masonry_item-->

<div class="masonry_item">
    <img src="images/cakes_home.jpg" alt="wonderfully whimsical cakes"/>
    <h3>Wonderfully Whimsical Cakes</h3>
</div> <!--masonry_item-->

</div><!--#masonry_container .group-->
```

CSS;

```
.group {
    display: inline-block;
    clear:both;
}

.group:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

#masonry_container {
margin:50px auto;
width:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:2001;
}

.masonry_item {
width:300px;
margin:0 0 20px 0px;
padding:20px;
}

.masonry_item:hover{ 
outline:1px solid white;
}

#masonry_container img {
width:100%;
}
```

and JS;

```
var container = document.querySelector('#masonry_container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    // options
    isFitWidth: true,
    itemSelector: '.masonry_item'
});
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the css:

```
.masonry_item {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto 20px auto;
  padding:20px;
}
```

**EDIT**

I didn't read this correctly the first time. If you want to center the actual container you will need to set a fixed size for the container instead of 100%. Maybe 500px. Then remove the display: inline-block from the .group class. That should do it.

Comment: Just removing display:inline-block did it. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for the edit. That "set a width on the container" gave me a very big leap of understanding for a related problem I was trying to solve.

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to figure this out for myself today and thought I'd share a possible solution.

As per Masonry's own options page `"isFitWidth": true` seems to be the key

http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isfitwidth

Here's their codepen example..

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nGLvx

Here's my simplified and bare bones method..

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/xtw113wx/2/ - code play

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/xtw113wx/2/embedded/result/ - full screen

**html**

```
<div class="masonry-container js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "isFitWidth": true }'>
    <div class="image-div">
        <img class="image" src="" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">
    </div>
    <!-- ..lots more divs in jsfiddle.. -->
</div>
```

**css**

```
.masonry-container {
    margin: 0 auto; /* this is the css that keeps the container centered in page */
}

.image-div {
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.image {
    width: 230px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Adding `isFitWidth = true` to initialisation of Masonry and `margin:0 auto;` to CSS of the container on which I initialize Masonry was enough to get it working.

Comment: update from 2019: the parameter name changed to fitWidth:
https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#fitwidth

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed size for the container, such as `width = 300px; height = 500px`.  Then, move the container with `left: 50%; top: 50%`.  Finally, set the `margin-left` to -1/2 the value of the width, and `margin-top` to -1/2 the value of the height.  This only works with absolute positioning.

Comment: Just a note that this won't work with responsive masonry, if you set a static width on the outer container it will prevent masonry from rearranging the items within the container. Use isFitWidth = true to have masonry automatically set the width on the outer container as and when it rearranges the container, this removes the need for hacky JS/Media queries to get it working.