# Center images in masonry

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I am using [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to place my images nicely on a large screen like this:

```
 <div class="grid"  >
    <div class="grid-item"><img class='link img-link' src="images/image1.gif"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img class='link img-link' src="images/image2.gif"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img class='link img-link' src="images/image3.gif"></div>
  </div>
```

and the following jQuery snipped

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.grid').masonry({
        columnWidth: 1,
        itemSelector: '.grid-item'
      });
});
```

However nice placing is not necessary when using a mobile phone.
Currently, on a mobile screen the images are not centered but all left aligned. Setting `text-align:center` to `grid` or `grid-item` does not help.
**How can I center the images when they are all listed underneath?**

The problem can be seen at http://www.kristianhammerstad.com/

[image]

This is how it looks in my case:

[image]

Comment: Please check this link:-http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

Comment: @Raziasultana I did.

Comment: @Raziasultana Do you think there is an option that centers the images? I checked the list and did not find any.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the pixels using from which you want to apply the rule and use the following:
For example, if you want 360 pixels and below: use the following code at your css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .box.col3.editorial , .box.col3.poster{
             left: 0;
             right: 0;
             margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.masonry_item {
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto 20px auto;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Again try this link:-
[How to Center Masonry Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390689/how-to-center-masonry-container)

Comment: Thank you. But your related question is about how to center the complete container, not the individual images. Also, my items have different width, so setting them all to `widht:300px` doesn't look like a good idea to me.